# ASP.NET MVC 3 model and viewmodel classes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel and it has a nested class what is not in connection other model class. I can fill the necessary data in this nested class (ClassX) to show those in the view but I can't get out data from the nested class (through MyViewModel) in the post action just when I give it in post action as another parameter. It appears in original viewmodel (MyViewModel) but its attributes are null/0.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public MyViewModel()
   {
      classX = new ClassX();
   }

   public ClassX classX;
   public int attrA {get;set;}
   ...
}
public class ClassX {}

//
// POST: /MyModel/Create
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel myvm, **ClassX cx**, FormCollection collection)
{}
```

My question: Can I read data out from the nested class through the viewmodel class?

Comment: Just a guess - I think the conversion process will only bring over properties.  I think you need to change "public ClassX classX;" to "public ClassX classX { get; set; }"

Comment: Thank you. I tried  your suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

http://goneale.com/2009/07/27/updating-multiple-child-objects-and-or-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-views/ this is a good article for you

```
  MyViewModel myViewModel= new MyViewModel();
  UpdateModel(myViewModel, "MyViewModel");
  myViewModel.myViewModel= new myViewModel();
  UpdateModel(myViewModel.classX, "User.classX");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need [BindAttribute.Prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.prefix.aspx) on your `ClassX cx` parameter of action method. This way, model binder will correctly bind values for it. The value for `Bind.Prefix` should be name of ClassX property in `MyViewModel`, in your example, the string - `"classX"`

```
//
// POST: /MyModel/Create
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel myvm, [Bind(Prefix = "classX")]ClassX cx, FormCollection collection)
{}
```

Idea is in the following - on client side, when you submit the form, its values are sent to server like this

```
attrA=someValue
classX.SomeProperty=someValue
classX.SomeOtherProperty=someOtherValue
```

When passed to action parameters, this name=value string pairs are translated to objects. Names from left side of equality match to property names of `MyViewModel`, and the ClassX parameter stays empty. But then you specify `Prefix = "classX"`, model binder matches strings after dot in left side of equality to ClassX property names, so that should fill values of ClassX too.